# bad result from numpy corrcoef and minimum spanning tree

Tags: numpy

I have this code:

```
mm = np.array([[1, 4, 7, 8], [2, 2, 8, 4], [1, 13, 1, 5]])
mm = np.column_stack(mm)

mmCov = np.cov(mm, rowvar=0)
print("covariance\n", mmCov)

# my code to get correlations
mmResCor = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3))
for i in range(len(mmCov)):
    for j in range(len(mmCov[i])):
        mmResCor[i][j] = mmCov[i][j] / (math.sqrt(mmCov[i][i] * mmCov[j] [j]))

print("correlaciones a mano\n", mmResCor)

mmCor = np.corrcoef(mmCov, rowvar=0)
print("correlations\n", mmCor)

X = csr_matrix(mmCor)
XX = minimum_spanning_tree(X)
print("minimun spanning tree\n", XX)
```

first: each column represents a variable, with observations in the rows

numpy corrcoef use this relation with covariance matrix:

```
 R_{ij} = \frac{ C_{ij} } { \sqrt{ C_{ii} * C_{jj} } }
```

when I use numpy corrcoef I get this matrix

```
 correlations
 [[ 1.          0.8660254  -0.82603319]
 [ 0.8660254   1.         -0.99717646]
 [-0.82603319 -0.99717646  1.        ]]
```

but when I apply "my code" to get the same result...

```
mmResCor = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3))
for i in range(len(mmCov)):
for j in range(len(mmCov[i])):
    mmResCor[i][j] = mmCov[i][j] / (math.sqrt(mmCov[i][i] * mmCov[j][j]))
```

I get this matrix

```
  correlaciones a mano
  [[ 1.          0.67082039  0.        ]
  [ 0.67082039  1.         -0.5       ]
  [ 0.         -0.5         1.        ]]
```

why do I get differents results if its suppose I am doing the same?

One more question:
When I apply minimun_spanning_tree I get this:

```
minimun spanning tree
(0, 2)  -0.826033187631
(1, 2)  -0.997176464953
```

Is there any way to represent these or can I save this result in some variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `np.corrcoef` should take the *data* as the input. You're passing the *covariance matrix* as input. If you pass the data, you get the same result as your manual computation:

```
>>> np.corrcoef(mm, rowvar=0)
array([[ 1.        ,  0.67082039,  0.        ],
       [ 0.67082039,  1.        , -0.5       ],
       [ 0.        , -0.5       ,  1.        ]])
```

Regarding the minimum spanning tree, I'm not sure what your question is, but the output `XX` is a sparse matrix which stores a matrix representation of the tree.

Comment: the question was if I could print the tree using the matplotlib library with output [XX] or i need to implement the algorithm of Kruskal with the output matrix mmCor

Comment: Yes, you could use the contents of ``XX`` to visualize the tree; here's an example with a more complicated dataset: http://www.astroml.org/paper_figures/CIDU2012/fig_great_wall_MST.html